# How can I tell when my MS Dynamics CRM trial key will expire?

Tags: licensing, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I have an installation of Dynamics CRM 2011 that is currently on a trial key.  We would like to change to a production license before it expires.  Is there somewhere in Deployment Manager or elsewhere that I can see how much time is remaining on the trial?

Comment: The trial keys work for 90 days after they're installed. Not sure if it shows that anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the answer after a little more digging so I'll provide that here:

The License Key is tracked in the MSCRM_CONFIG database under the ConfigSettings table according to [this thread](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdeployment/thread/febfbd9c-a360-4193-bebe-86bb866044f6):

```
SELECT LicenseKey FROM dbo.ConfigSettings
```

So checking the other columns in the ConfigSettings table I found the InstallOn column.  I assume that this is the date that the trial key was applied as part of the installation wizard.  The following query will then show how many days are remaining in your trial:

```
SELECT 
InstallOn, 
DATEADD(d,90,InstallOn) AS ExpiresOn, 
DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE(),DATEADD(d,90,InstallOn)) AS DaysRemaining
FROM dbo.ConfigSettings
```

The results will look something like this:

```
InstallOn               ExpiresOn               DaysRemaining
----------------------- ----------------------- -------------
2012-01-29 11:56:26.547 2012-04-28 11:56:26.547 82
```